# Computing properties from nested objects in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I need to display the result of a method in my Ember.js handlebars template. From what I understand, I must use a computed property to do this. The issue I'm having is the property relies on a nested object which does not seem to trigger a change event when changed/set, as I'm only changing its internal structure. Here's short example of my situation:

```
App.Foo = Ember.Object.extend({
    prop: {
        fizz: {}
    },

    init: function() {
        var prop = this.get("prop");
        prop.fizz.buzz = "foobar";
        this.set("prop", prop); // This doesn't seem to fire a change event
    },

    handlebarsValue: function() {
        var prop = this.get("prop");
        // ...
        // compute this property from the properties of `prop`
        // ...
        return prop.fizz.buzz;
    }.property("prop")
});
```

Template:

```
<p>handlebarsValue: {{model.handlebarsValue}}</p>
```

Is there any way to force an update on the computed property? Is there a better way to do this? Am I misunderstanding the 'Ember way'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the Ember.Object.set(key, value) method and notify property observers that your property has changed.

```
// http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_set
set: function(key, value) {
  this._super(key, value);

  // Are we updating any nested attributes of our property 'prop'?
  if (key.indexOf('prop.') > -1) {

    // then notify property observers
    this.notifyPropertyChange('prop');
  }
}
```

JSBin demo here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zagisona/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

The `propertyWillChange` method seems to work for alerting Ember to changing properties. I'm still not sure if this is the most optimal solution, but it works for my circumstances.

```
App.Foo = Ember.Object.extend({
        prop: {
            fizz: {}
        },

        init: function() {
            var prop = this.get("prop");
            this.propertyWillChange("prop");
            prop.fizz.buzz = "foobar";
            this.set("prop", prop); // This doesn't seem to fire a change event
        },

        handlebarsValue: function() {
            var prop = this.get("prop");
            // ...
            // compute this property from the properties of `prop`
            // ...
            return prop.fizz.buzz;
        }.property("prop")
    });
```